# How do I change extensions of different file types

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, file-format

I have many files with different extensions in one directory (for example `.aa`, `.1ab`, `.412` . etc). How can I change extensions of all this files to `.txt` There is now other files in folder, only those I want to change extensions.

Thank You.

Comment: Why change the extension? You can open simple text files with Mousepad, Leafpad or other Notepad-like app directly, no matter what the extension may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for IF in *.* ; do OF="${IF%.*}.txt" ; mv -n $IF $OF ; done
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `-n` or `--no-clobber` to the `mv` command just in case any names conflict after changing the suffix

Comment: Edited. Also, mv will complain about both source and destination files are identical. I don't know how to avoid this except maybe redirecting STDERR to /dev/null.